# Parsing Hijri Date in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, date-parsing, hijri

I want to parse Hijri Date in Spring Boot. In my application Hijri date will come as `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. I want to parse it in the `"dd/MM/yyyy"` format. I am having issue for `29/02` and `30/02` date consider as `01/03` and `02/03` respectively.

Comment: Can you please show us an example input `String` and what you have done so far?

Comment: From what you have written (which is not that much) I guess you are using a `java.util.Date`, is that correct? If yes, stop using it and have a look at [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your input date-format is same as the ISO8601 format and therefore you won't need to define a `DateTimeFormatter` for it. However, you will need to define one for the output string.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.chrono.HijrahChronology;
import java.time.chrono.HijrahDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-string
        String dateStr = "2020-09-23";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Formatter for output string
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        // Get HijrahDate corresponding to the given LocalDate
        HijrahDate hijrahDate = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(date);

        // Print the default format
        System.out.println(hijrahDate);
        // Print the string using custom format
        System.out.println(hijrahDate.format(outputFormatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-23
Hijrah-umalqura AH 1442-02-06
06/02/1442
```